# How can I create headers like these with Latex?

Tags: header-footer

I recently changed from Word to Latex, and I am not ready to say goodbye to my usual headers.
I tried the fancyhdr package, but it gives this annoying line I don't like and messes up my alignment symbols for some reason...

This is how I would like my header to look like, I would appreciate any help
thank you[image]

This is all i have

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Name}
\chead{Topic}
\rhead{Class}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

How can i create a second header row (like in the image) and how can i get rid of the line?

Comment: Could you post what you tried with fancyhdr?  It probably only needs a slight tweaking.

Comment: Have a look at fancyhdr on ctan.org .

Comment: The line of fancyhdr can be removed. Can you show us a small, but compilable text document which shows us what you have, I'm sure we can help you with the rest.

Comment: I have included code now, i hope it helps. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to remove the rule, you could either set its width to zero or redefine the `\headrule` macro to do nothing
- As a quick hack to get multiline headers, you can insert `\linebreak`. If you need more elaborate means to change e.g. alignment, you could use a tabular in your header. (the two line header will require a larger `\headheight`)

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Name\linebreak text}
\chead{Topic\linebreak text}
\rhead{Class\linebreak text}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{}

\setlength{\headheight}{23pt}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I wanted

Comment: @434dx You're welcome!